# Is it possible to automatically grant dangerous permissions to pre-installed OS apps?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Let's say an app requires the CAMERA permission and that we are providing our app to the device vendor to be pre-installed on the device, as part of the device OS. Is it possible for this permission to be granted automatically without asking a user, like this is done e.g. for the base camera app which is provided by the OS by default ?

Comment: After android marshmallow no.

Comment: i've updated your question a bit to make the point a bit clearer, please let me know if this doesn't fit what you were asking so i can undo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Check this documentation on [privileged permission whitelisting](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist).

IIRC, the user can still revoke these permissions so your app must be prepared to work without this permission. All it guarantees is that the permission is granted to the app out of the box.

Comment: this is very cool, but it seems to be only available for "Privileged apps" "[which] are system apps that are located in a priv-app directory on one of the system image partitions. "

Comment: Yes. OP did mention that their app will be pre-installed on a device so the OEM vendor can arrange for this.

Comment: i upvoted your answer, simply because i didn't know about the privileged permission system, very interesting

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887406/6477592

Answer (score 2):

No, not if the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher,

> The purpose of a permission is to protect the privacy of an Android
> user. Android apps **must** request permission to access sensitive user
> data (such as contacts and SMS), as well as certain system features
> (such as camera and internet). Depending on the feature, the system
> might grant the permission automatically or might prompt the user to
> approve the request.
>
> A central design point of the Android security architecture is **that no
> app, by default, has permission to perform any operations that would
> adversely impact other apps, the operating system, or the user.** This
> includes reading or writing the user's private data (such as contacts
> or emails), reading or writing another app's files, performing network
> access, keeping the device awake, and so on.

(emphasis mine)
Taken from [permission overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

This simply isn't possible, unless you're potentially using a custom version of android and you have control over the OS

Comment: While I completely agree with you when we are speaking about usual apps found in Play Store, in our case this is a pre-installed app approved by a device vendor, so I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674310/1776585 to be on point.

Comment: no worries @MikhailKadan, very interesting answer indeed !

Answer (score 0):

Simply It is not possible. @curioustechizen answer is totally wrong. Privileged permission is different from dangerous permission.

Dangerous permission must be granted at run time only. User should aware of the dangerous permissions which are used in the application.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: If your app is pre-installed then it is possible even for dangerous permissions. See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/runtime_perms#creating-exceptions

The goal is for apps that are default handlers for functionality like calling/SMS. I'm not sure if `CAMERA` permission is part of this though.